# How to support byte range requests in ingress-nginx for Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, safari, kubernetes

I am using ingress-nginx for Kubernetes to serve mp4 video files. It is working fine except in iOS browser. According to Apple developer site:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006514-SW6

The Http server must support byte-range requests.
According to the following Stackflow post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728016/nginx-is-not-accepting-range-of-bytes

The byte-range support can be turned on for Nginx by using proxy_force_ranges on;

However, the configMap of ingress-nginx does not support this parameter.

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/

Does anyone know how can I change the settings of ingress-nginx to support the iOS browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Configuration Snippet Annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet) to add additional configuration to your NGINX locations.

Add the following annotation to your Ingress resource:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  proxy_force_ranges "On";
```